# how to make 2 columns with sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to make multiple columns on my documentation.

Globally, i would like to do something similar as [this homepage](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Main_Page), where there is 3 columns : one with current release, one with news & updates, and Basics.

When i search on google about multiple columns in Sphinx, i found about splitting a list in 2 columns which is not my case

On the wiki the only things i found with multiple columns is the table, but i don't think this can apply here ?

Is this possible in rst files using Sphinx ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know of any 3-column Sphinx themes. You can create a custom theme. It's not easy, though. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/theming.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok i finally found it :

you can use `container` keyword in sphinx/rst files to separate things

```
.. container:: twocol

    .. container:: leftside

        text on left column

    .. container:: rightside

        text on right column
```

And then in your .css file :

```css
div.leftside {
  width: 43%;
  padding: 0px 3px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
}

div.rightside {
  margin-left: 45%;
  /* float: right; */
}
```

With this method, you can write everything you want in the container (image, links, text, ... and it will be displayed properly.

Comment: This works for me, but I can't see how to *end* it.  If I leave a few blank lines and start a new paragraph or even a heading it stays in the right column until they have reached even length.  I guess it means you have to balance them by hand.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: Did you indent your code well and put enough line returns ? I don't know if it is usefull, but i use cloud theme in sphinx. So on my css file there is some imports : "@import url("default.css");
@import url("cloud.css");"

Comment: Did you ever figure that one out? @markgalassi

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of an old question, but a potentially better answer to this question nowadays is to use https://sphinx-panels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

That extension provides various components that you don't have in plain reST.

Comment: It should be noted that IMO `panels` look best with the [`furo` theme](https://pradyunsg.me/furo/quickstart/).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this, so either you find a three-columns-based sphinx theme (not that I know of any) or as [@Steve_Piercy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2214933/steve-piercy) suggested you can create your own theme, which will probably be quite the task. However, you can instead use a theme of choice and simply adjust your `.rst` file content and overwrite your theme to display your content in  3 columns fashion. To do that you need some HTML and CSS though.

So first you need to create a `test.rst` with your content as html raw code like the following:

```
Test
======

.. raw:: html

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now that the content is ready, we create a style file for it under `_static/custom_style.css` that includes the following code:

```
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

The last step is to add this style to your `conf.py` file in order for it to be added it to your theme. So in your `conf.py` add the following lines:

```py
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('custom_style.css')
```

That's it, now run and test. The output should look somewhat like this (depending on your theme):
[image]

Comment: Oh Thanks you. I'll try it and give you some updates.
However, i'm not very fluent with css, so maybe this is a stupid question : 
Is it possible to parameter the height of the columns ? I see you specified height: 500px. But what if i don't know about the height my column will have ?
Thanks again

Comment: I think you can drop that line and your column will just fit your page height. I am not that fluent in CSS either. I usually just try stuff and see what works best.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the [sphinx-design](https://sphinx-design.readthedocs.io/en/rtd-theme/grids.html) extension which is the successor to panels. Importantly, this does not require you to configure any html or css.

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to add a comment to the accepted solution from LudwigVonKoopa but there is the question how to end the two column setting.
Additionally to the accepted solution and based on the answer from SuperKogito, I added this to my css file:

```
/* Clear floats after the columns */
div.after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

This allows to end the two column part with

```
.. |space| unicode:: U+0020 .. space

.. container:: twocol

    .. container:: leftside

       Left side text

    .. container:: rightside
     
       Right side text


.. container:: after

   |space|
```

This does not generate a line in the html output but it ends the two column part.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34139940)

Comment: Hi bfontaine, I think it clearly answers the question from @markgalasi in the comments on the accepted solution „how to make the two columns“ stop. No other solutin than to balance the columns manually was proposed. My solution is different to that.